# Ember Simple Auth - always login

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm working on a closed system where you always need to be logged in.   Mixing in the AuthenticatedRouteMixin does not work at the root (applicationroute) level.

I suppose I could probably embed the login form and handle login on the root page, but how would I go about redirecting the root route to the login route?

Ideally I would like to treat the root route just like AuthenticatedRouteMixin.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to add an `/internal` route and redirect to that from the root route if the user is logged in. You'd also mix in the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin` in the `internal` route. The login UI would be displayed on the root route then.

Comment: So you could make the root route the login route and redirect into the 'tree' that way.   Decent option.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (updated answer):  Even simpler just add the following to "routes/index.js"

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin);
```

---

Original answer: Ok, I figured this out.  I was confusing/mixing ApplicationRoute with the root IndexRoute.   It's about as easy as I thought it should be.

I'm Using ember-cli.   This assumes you mixin ApplicationRouteMixin on the ApplicationRoute so session is available.

Create a route file for the root index route (routes/index.js)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function () {
    var session = this.get('session');
    if (!session.isAuthenticated) {
      this.transitionTo('login');
    }
  }
});
```